# Could Kreia's plan to destroy the Force actually succeed?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, video-games

In the Star Wars video game [Knights of the Old Republic II](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars%3a_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II%3a_The_Sith_Lords), the final antagonist, [Kreia (Darth Traya)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Traya) wanted to completely destroy the Force by sacrificing herself in the [wound in the force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Wound_in_the_Force) on Malachor V. This should generate a chain reaction to destroy the force.

Obviously her plan failed before it could be implemented, but could it have worked? And wouldn't that have eliminated all life and cosmic structure as well? The Force=Life Life is the Force.

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: Not a book, KOTOR II

Comment: I would explain more maybe a few quotes from something.  It doesnt make much sense to those of us who do not know about the plan, but have the type of knowledge to answer this hypo

Comment: How do you know she failed? We just live in the alternate universe where she succeeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine it would be similar to what the Sith Emperor did on Nathema.

From *Revan*

> "But the ritual was not confined to the doomed Sith Lords. They were but the eye of the storm; the center of a vortex that spread across the entire planet. Every man, woman, and child on Nathema died that day. Every beast, bird, and fish; all the insects and plants; every living being touched by the Force was consumed. When the ritual ended, Nathema was no longer a world. It was a husk sucked dry. Lord Vitiate sacrificed millions, stealing their life force to make himself immortal. Their deaths also made him stronger than any Sith who had come before, and he ceased to be known as Lord Vitiate. On that day, the Emperor was truly born."

This is what was known as "The Void", where every living thing that was touched by the Force was dead.  The planet was still there and accessible (It was later visited by The Exile and Revan) but the Force was simply not present.

As for if Kreia's plan would've worked?  Kreia had the gift of foresight, as she was able to tell the destinies of The Exile and her companions at the end of the game, it's logical to believe that she saw what the universe would be like if her plan succeeded.